# IOS UITableView - Method that is fired when navigating away?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableviewcontroller with two editable fields - if selected to edit - a modal view appears with a text box - the data is then submitted to the field in the parent uitableviewcontroller.

The brief is for a tick to appear alongside a field when edited - so the user knows it has been updated - this all works fine - but when navigating away from to anywhere other than the modal view I would like to hide the ticks - else they have little effect on repeat visits!

Is there a method I could use which would fire when navigating to anywhere other than the modal view?  or could anyone suggest a way to achieve this logic on uitableview load?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `BOOL` var as `iVar`, Then assign that value with `YES` when you call the push action method.

For Example:

In .h file

```
BOOL isEdited;
```

In .m file

```
-(void)nextTapped
{
    isEdited = NO;

    [tableView reloadData];
    //push view controller code here
}
```